# How to identity non-empty columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, isnullorempty

I'm processing a dataset with around 2000 columns and I noticed many of them are empty. I want to know specifically how many of them are empty and how many are not. I use the following code:

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

I will get the number of empty rows in each columns. However, given I'm investigating about 2000 columns with 7593 rows, the output in IPython looks like the following:

```
FEMALE_DEATH_YR3_RT              7593
FEMALE_COMP_ORIG_YR3_RT          7593
PELL_COMP_4YR_TRANS_YR3_RT       7593
PELL_COMP_2YR_TRANS_YR3_RT       7593
                             ... 
FIRSTGEN_YR4_N                   7593
NOT1STGEN_YR4_N                  7593
```

It doesn't show all the columns because it has too many columns. Thus it makes it very difficult to tell how many columns are all empty and how any are not.
I wonder is there anyway to allow me to identify the non-empty columns quickly? Thanks!

Comment: `s=df.isnull().any();s[s.values]`

Comment: `v = df.isnull().sum(); v.index[v.gt(0)].tolist()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
to find the number of non empty columns:
```

> len(df.columns) - len(df.dropna(axis=1,how='all').columns)

```
3
```

df

```
  Country   movie name  rating  year  Something
0     thg    John    3     NaN   NaN        NaN
1     thg     Jan    4     NaN   NaN        NaN
2     mol  Graham  lob     NaN   NaN        NaN

df=df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')

  Country   movie name
0     thg    John    3
1     thg     Jan    4
2     mol  Graham  lob
```